# A good explanation for dart assert statement

Tags: flutter, dart

This code is from `flutter` sdk.

I can not understand `assert((){}())` expression.

It from the `setState()` function.

```
  assert(() {
          if (result is Future) {
            throw FlutterError(
              'setState() callback argument returned a Future.\n'
              'The setState() method on $this was called with a closure or method that '
              'returned a Future. Maybe it is marked as "async".\n'
              'Instead of performing asynchronous work inside a call to setState(), first '
              'execute the work (without updating the widget state), and then synchronously '
              'update the state inside a call to setState().'
            );
          }
          // We ignore other types of return values so that you can do things like:
          //   setState(() => x = 3);
          return true;
        }());
```

I have tested the code below.

`b` was not print.

```
main() {
  assert(() {
    print("b");
  } ());
  print("a");
}
```

Comment: please read this https://www.w3adda.com/dart-tutorial/dart-assert-statement

Comment: Your `assert` isn't returning anything. An `assert` argument in the format `() { <code> } ()` needs to return a boolean: `true` for if the assertion passes; `false` for if the assertion fails.

Comment: I run the code in dart playground, thus the `b` not print.